# testSuccess method implementation for RunListener interface

Tags: java

I have a class that extends RunListener interface (JUnit framework) so i will be able to perform different action depending on the test result.
My issue is that the interface has no testSuccess method. (for example the ITestListener from TEstNG framework has a onTestSuccess method)
Should i create my own testSuccess method in the class extending RunListener or what can i do?

thank you

RunListener class
http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html
Example of implementation
https://memorynotfound.com/add-junit-listener-example/

i expected that the RunListener interface will have a testSuccess method but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final Description FAILED = Description.createTestDescription("failed", "failed");

public void testFinished(Description description) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Finished test: " + description.getMethodName());
        if (description.getChildren().contains(FAILED)) {
            // action for test failed
        } else {
            // action for test success 
        }
    }

    public void testFailure(Failure failure) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Failed test: " + failure.getDescription().getMethodName());

// mark the test as being failed 
        failure.getDescription().addChild(FAILED);
    }
```